# How can I do this angle symbol?

Tags: symbols

[image: angle symbol]

How can I make the angle symbol  with LaTeX?

Comment: Try package `amssymb` and `$\sphericalangle$`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character

Comment: $\sphericalangle$ looks otherwise

Comment: `\AngleSign `from `marvosym`.

Answer (score 8):

The symbol in the picture seems to have been built from the “less than” symbol and a parenthesis. I also present an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for \sphericalangle

\newcommand{\arcangle}{%
  \mathord{<\mspace{-9mu}\mathrel{)}\mspace{2mu}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\arcangle ABC=45^\circ$

$\sphericalangle ABC=45^\circ$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the symbol centered with respect to capital letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\arcangle}{\mathord{\mathpalette\doarcangle\relax}}
\newcommand{\doarcangle}[2]{%
  \hbox{%
    \sbox0{$#1B$}%
    \sbox2{$#1<$}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp2+(\ht0-\ht2)/2}{%
      $#1<\mspace{-9mu}\mathrel{)}\mspace{2mu}$%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\arcangle ABC=45^\circ$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user149743 Just a remark: the symbol you'd like to get looks horrible. `;-)`

Comment: how i do vertical alignment this symbol?

Comment: @user149743 I added a way to raise the symbol